# Plaing an .swf file with external resources in 2021

Tags: flash

I have an old CD that came as a media material with a textbook. It consists of a directory tree with .swf files as well as other files which they are referring: media, .xml, other .swf files. For instance, some of the .swf files seem to be chapter-level menus and were designed to provide navigation to other .swf files.

Now in 2021 I only managed to open single .swf files in Ruffle for Windows and it doesn't help because it's obvious that they miss some resources to load properly.

Is there a way to literally travel the technology back and open it as it has been designed to be opened, maybe I could deploy some .swf-related IDE and make it work to get access to the content in the "Debug" mode, if there was such a thing in the SWF/Adobe Flash ecosystem?

Comment: Have you tried downloading [Flash Player projector content debugger](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) and opening the main SWF with that?

Comment: @VC.One Thank you, I actually managed to open it because I was not careful in the first place: the CD's iso-file contained a Windows executable which turned out to be the "main" app from which all the internal resources work properly. They are using .swf under the hood, but somehow it still manages to work in 2021!